# Showing that the power series has the explicit formula

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to show that $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k}{k}x^n = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in (-1, 1)$.

I have tried out a couple values for $k$ and $x \in (-1, 1)$ and the formula seems to be true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Induction.

**Outline of proof:**

Prove first for $k=0$, then induction, using that the derivative of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$ is $\frac{k+1}{(1-x)^{k+2}}$.

Then use:

$$\binom{n+k}{k}\cdot \frac{n}{k+1} = \binom{n-1+(k+1)}{k+1}$$

Comment: Isn't the derivative of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$ $\frac{-(k+1)}{(1-x)^{k+2}}$?

Comment: @SeojunHong Nope - the derivative of $\frac{1}{(1+x)^{k+1}}$ is $\frac{-(k+1)}{(1+x)^{k+2}}$, but you forgot the $-$ in the $1-x$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** As I wrote [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488056), $~\displaystyle{n+k\choose k}={n+k\choose n}=(-1)^n~{-k-1\choose n}.~$ Use this, to rewrite

the expression in terms of the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).